# TypeError: calendar.rerenderEvents is not a function - Fullcalendar Rerender Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I have a fullcalendar 4 installation via script tags, not ES6 working as expected. I am using a modal to input information and sending the form to ajax to submit - also working as expected.

On success callback, i'm logging results into console and then closing the modal and looking to rerender/refetch the events reflect the form submission but receiving the following in console:

> TypeError: calendar.rerenderEvents is not a function`

Ajax is the following:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: form.attr("action"),
  data: form.serialize(),
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response),
      $("#createbulk").modal('hide');
    calendar.rerenderEvents();
  }
});
```

I've tried jquery noconflict and that produced further issue so reverted back, I've also moved the script tags around to see if that made a difference but had no success.

--
EDIT: calendar is defined at the top of the page, along with the configuration options.

`var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
 var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {`

Comment: Given the error it would appear that the `calendar` variable does not hold a reference to a FullCalendar instance. Where have you defined it? Is it in scope of the AJAX block? Can you please add more of the relevant code to the question.

Comment: calendar might not be defined, where do you import the calendar ?

Comment: It's defined at the top of the page along with the configuration, edited the initial question to include this information. Would the calendar have to be redefined inside the ajax block?

Comment: No, re-defining it would make no sense. But you do need to ensure it's in scope.

Comment: How would you go about doing that? I've built a function inside and outside the blocks and researched extending varibles outside scopes but had no luck so far.